# PHP Laravel how to change the ouput language

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to change the output language in `Laravel` ? I have a list of releases which is sorted my the release_date and grouped into months. Now I want the ouptut e.g. the frontend to display them in for example german, but right now the months only gets outputtet in english.

Here is my controller:

```
public function index() {

    $releases = Release::orderBy('release_date', 'asc')
    ->get()->groupBy('release_date.localeMonth');

    return view('pages.index')->with('release_months', $releases);      

}
```

and my view file:

```
@foreach ($release_months as $month => $release_months)
<section class="block releases">
  <h2>{{$month}}</h2>
  <div class="releases-wrapper">
    @foreach ($release_months as $release)
    <div class="release">
        <div class="release__date">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($release->release_date)->format('d. M')}}</div>
        <div class="release__details">{{$release->artist}} - {{$release->album_title}} 
            @if ($release->album_type != 'Full')
            <span class="release__type">({{$release->album_type}})</span>
        @endif
        </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
  </div>
</section>
@endforeach
```

Can I do this with Carbon too or do I need some kind of `months.php` file ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Carbon suports [localization](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization). You can change the language using the `locale` function. In your case, like so:

```
echo \Carbon\Carbon::parse($release->release_date)->locale('de')->format('d. M')
```

Comment: When I try to use that I get `Method locale does not exist` ? :-s